# Design of method using ref to alter partially immutable class

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, architecture

In my project I have a header class that represents a globally unique key for a piece of information inside the system, such as who it belongs to, what time it exists for, etc. Inside the same header class I also have fields for information that is specific to a given instance of data, such as who created this version of the information, when it was created, if its new data that needs to be saved to the database, etc.

Here is an example of stocking some information into a data transport class and querying it back out.

```
var header = new IntvlDataHeader(
       datapoint: Guid.NewGuid(),
       element: Guid.NewGuid(),
       intervalUtc: DateTime.Now.Date);

package.StockData_Decimal(header, 5m);

decimal cloneData;
package.TryGetData_Decimal(ref header, out cloneData);

// header now refers to a different object, that could have different flags/information
```

Note how I made the TryGetData_Decimal pass the header variable by reference. IntvlDataHeader is a class, and if the data is found inside TryGetData then the reference is changed to point to a new instance of IntvlDataHeader that has the specific instance information in addition to having the same unique key information.

Is combining a key with instance specific information and using a ref parameter as both in and out a bad design? Would the effort of splitting out another class so that there would be two out parameters and no ref parameters be better or avoid any potential problems?

The signature of the method is `public bool TryGetData_Decimal(ref IntvlDataHeader header, out decimal data)`

Comment: Wow, `TryGetData_Decimal` is truly horrible. Why not use generics and have something akin to `TryGetData<decimal>`?

Comment: For a couple reasons, the underlying system only supports 5 predetermined datatypes. I could have just TryGetData, but then there would be 15 overloads, it seemed cleaner just from an intellisense manner to have only 3 overloads with the type in the name. Also there is type specific code that has to be run, for String and Guid datatypes the system is using dictionary based compression that it doesn't use for the other types. So using a generic method would require another level of indirection. There are generic private methods that handle the call internally after the public call to *_Decimal

Comment: Cool, good to know this was intentional decision. Thanks for letting us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the naming of your `TryGetData_Decimal` is misleading, if the `ref` parameter your passing in will then point to a new instance when the method exits.  `TryGetData_Decimal`, to me, sounds like a variation of the `TryParse` methods on a number of value types (which has an out parameter containing the parsed value - similar to the `cloneData` parameter).

I guess I'm not sure why the header object has to point to a new instance, so I'm not sure I can recommend a design.  If that's what you need to do, I think it may be more readable if your `TryGetData_XXX` methods have a signature something like this:

```
IntvlDataHeader ExtractValueAndGetNewInstance_Decimal(IntvlDataHeader header, out decimal cloneData)
```

where header is passed in, but doesn't change when the method exits.  The method returns the new instance, and you can use it if you need it.  I wouldn't change the `cloneData` - I think `out` parameters are OK as long as they aren't overused.

I'd try to change the name of the method to something more meaningful, too.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't show it in the example, but the method signature is `public bool TryGetData_Decimal(ref IntvlDataHeader header, out decimal data)`, it returns a true/false if it found that header at all. And then only if it returns true will header be modified to point to a different instance with possibly different flags and some other information